# Keycloak backchannel logout URL mechanism not working as expected

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect

I am currently trying to get the backchannel logout to work. The System which allows SSO via Keycloak is complex, outdated and manages users itself. That's why Keycloak is only relevant for the login - invalidating the access token or even terminating Keycloak in Docker will not result in authentication errors.

As far as my understanding of backchannel logout goes, it is made for exactly this use case. In the OAuth 2.0 specification, which is the basis for OpenID Connect, which in turn in used by Keycloak, the backchannel logout is defined as follows:

[image]
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html

Keycloak offers the input of a backchannel logout URL per client. So, I created a POST endpoint and provided the URL to that endpoint in Keycloak, but nothing happens. I'm stuck here.